# Returning Success / Error messages - Laravel & VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I am tinkering with an image uploader which will preview the image before uploading.

There are restrictions in place to allow just jpg, jpeg or png image formats, however, the error messages aren't being returned and I have tried a number of methods Please see my code below:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img :src="image" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" @click="upload">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is being designed using Vue and Laravel. I am literally 1 day into learning Vue so please let me know if I have missed a vital part you need to look at (such as the route/controller)

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                image: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImage(files[0]);
            },
            createImage(file) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                let vm = this;
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.image = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            upload(){
                axios.post('/api/upload',{image: this.image})
                    .then(response => {

                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please see the controller below:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'image' => 'required|image64:jpeg,jpg,png'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
        } else {
            $imageData = $request->get('image');
            $fileName = Carbon::now()->timestamp . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($imageData, 0, strpos($imageData, ';')))[1])[1];
            Image::make($request->get('image'))->save(public_path('images/').$fileName);
            return response()->json(['error'=>false]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you returning if you get any error message from laravel ?

Comment: @user, I have added the controller in for you to refer to. I have also added a custom message within validation.php: `'image64'              => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate form and return error from laravel controller as

```
private function validateForm($advsearch){
    $validator = Validator::make($advsearch, [
        'fname' => 'required',
    ]);
    return $validator;
}

public function submitForm(Request $request){
    $validator = $this->validateForm($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['isvalid'=>false,'errors'=>$validator->messages()]);
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

And display in vue by binding

```
<div>{{errors.fname?errors.fname[0]:''}}</div>
```

if you already bind `errors` in vue data

```
   data() {
        return {
            errors:[],
            image: ''
        }
   },
```

And update it after submit and if you get any error

```
  axios.post('/api/upload',{image: this.image})
     .then(response => {
         if(response.isValid == false){
            this.errors = response.errors;
         }
  });
```

in your update you can check errors exist or not by `if(response.body.errors !== undefined){`

Comment: in your update you can check errors exist or not by `if(response.body.errors !== undefined){`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's throwing an error currently of: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined`

Comment: yes because I used `json(['isvalid'=>false,'errors'=>$validator->messages()])` in controller

Comment: I added this within the controller also?

Comment: replace `if(response.body.isValid == false){` by `if(response.body.errors !== undefined){` in axios

Comment: I think you need not to use `.body` remove and try `response.isValid` or just share what you get in `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: my console error is; app.js:43297 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
    at app.js:43297
    at <anonymous>

Comment: what you get in `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: response
:
"{"isvalid":false,"errors":{"image":["The image must be a file of type: jpeg,jpg,png."]}}"
responseText
:
"{"isvalid":false,"errors":{"image":["The image must be a file of type: jpeg,jpg,png."]}}"

Comment: ok, you just need `if(response.isValid == false){
                this.errors = response.errors;
             }`

Comment: I think you are now able to display error as you just need to fix you object and binding in vuejs

Comment: It's rather odd.. if i `console.log(response.data.errors.image)` it displays fine.. If i backtrack it slightly to give the isValid value it returns undefined

Comment: Was a damned Typo hah! I have it working now! Thanks for your help!

Comment: one last thing... My outputs working but in an odd format: `[ "The image must be a file of type: jpeg,jpg,png." ]`

Comment: use `[0]` like this `{{errors.fname?errors.fname[0]:''}}` for `fname`

Comment: Found an alternative method by using `v-for` but yours is just as good given it only has 1 required field. Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`response.data.isValid` use this instead of `response.isValid` in uppercase